# What's a good advanced textbook/resource for studying the complexity of counting and combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, complexity

I'm taking a class in enumerative combinatorics. The professor focusses on the complexity of solving combinatorics problems like partitions etc. I'm using Enumerative Combinatorics but it does not talk about complexity. What's a good book/website/resource that touches on enumerative (or even extremal) combinatorics and complexity of counting?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for a book (chapter) on counting complexity. In this case, I'd recommend the book of Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak, which has a chapter on counting complexity. A draft of it can be found [here](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/).

Concerning Extremal Combinatorics, Wiki suggests reading [Extremal and Probabilistic Combinatorics](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/epc7.pdf) by Noga Alon and Michael Krivelevich which contains pointers to some resources (mainly graph-related).